# Passing iOS sprites from one class to another

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a `Spritekit` project in xcode on my main screen. However I would really like to manage it from another class so as to not cluster my main. So I added a new class to manage and handle it. Sadly I can't seem to get it to show in my main (or I might be doing it wrong). My `myscene.m` consists of pretty much the same code including the spaceship and this is where I moved the code too ( I didn't bother adding the methods like `touchesBegan`)

```
//  joysitck.m
//  controlpad
//


#import "joysitck.h"


@implementation joysitck
{
    BOOL controlButtonOn;
}
float controlx=200;
float controly=200;
float touchX = 0.0;
float touchY=0.0;


- (instancetype)init
    {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            self.name = @"controlPadNode";

        SKSpriteNode *controlPadNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"game-controller-frontb"];

        controlPadNode.position = CGPointMake(controlx,controly);
        [controlPadNode setScale:0.5];
        controlPadNode.name = @"controlPadNode";
        controlPadNode.zPosition = 1.0;

        [self addChild:controlPadNode];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        touchX = location.x;
        touchY = location.y;
        controlButtonOn= true;
    }
}

//when touch moves
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        touchX = location.x;
        touchY = location.y;
        controlButtonOn= true;
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if control pad touched
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"controlPadNode"]) {
        controlButtonOn= false;
    }
}

//update method
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (controlButtonOn) {

        //the control pad
        SKNode *controlNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"controlPadNode"];
        SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"spaceShipNode"];     
        float angle = atan2f (touchY - controly, touchX - controlx) ;
        SKAction *moveShip=[SKAction moveByX:6*cosf(angle) y:0 duration:0.005];
        [node runAction: moveShip];

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: search the node tree to get the desired nodes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW17

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have added the code below too my main scene however the control pad does not show. did i miss something?
 -(SKNode *)controlPadNode
{
     return [self childNodeWithName:@"controlPad"];
}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I would like to put my dpad in a class oof it's own but it doesnt show when i try

Comment: Show the class of dpad and show how do you try to use it

Comment: @AndreyGordeev
ok i posted the init of the dpad in it's own class above, i also added how i try to call it from my mainscene

Comment: You specified a name of `joystic` node as "dpad". Then why you are trying to access it with using "controlPAdNode" name instead of "dpad"?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev
It was actually a typo. i changed both the names too ControlPadNode

Comment: Have you added "controlPadNode" to the scene?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev
Im gonna have too say no, me being under the impression that once i import the joystick.h file it can access it

Comment: Paste an entire code from  MyScene.m

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45568/discussion-between-sleep-paralysis-and-andrey-gordeev)

Comment: @AndreyGordeev
Removed the code not related to the dpad to make it shorter

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added `joystick` node to the scene.

Add this code to `MyScene`'s `initWithSize` method (before `[self addship]`):

```
joysitck *joysitckNode = [[joysitck alloc] init];
[self addChild:joysitckNode];
```

Comment: Still see no joystick, btw on your second line you meant joystickNode right? did i add the joystick in joystick.m correctly?

Comment: Yes. What is a type of `joysitck`? Maybe something wrong with `position`, try to play with different values

Comment: Ah yes...it does show but it was the position. Also, all the methods like touches began and the update, shouldnt they be in the joystick.m file?joystick shows but now doesnt move the spaceship node. (which is defined in m). Do i add the spaceship as a child in joystick.m?

Comment: Added more of the joystick method

Comment: I don't think you should move those methods to joystick.m file. You're setting `controlButtonOn`, which is unaccessible from joystick class

Comment: Even if I declare it in joystick.m?

Comment: When thejoystick is in the main it works and the spaceship is there too, and when it is in it's own class it shows but doesnt move the ship. Is it because the joystick cannot access the spaceship node? to move it?